# sed command error: preserving permissions for './seduEguCh': Operation not permitted

Tags: sed

I can't find how to fix an error message from a `sed` command. I'm running a shell script on Ubuntu on Windows 10 (with Windows Subsystem for Linux feature turned on). The line that's causing an error is this:

```
sed -i -e 's/ 841 bp//' Prot.fasta
```

`Prot.fasta` file is a list of sequences I've generated from the shell script, and each sequence looks like this:

```
>Emiliania_huxleyi_CCMP1516_tax280463_locID_jgi|Emihu1|426057|estExtDG_Genewise1PlusC_50194_seqID3655840 841 bp
------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------MASARLAIEGRVERQPIFRRLRGSE
```

I'm just trying to remove the `841 bp` part at the end of each sequence. But when I run the script, the line of code above gives me the following error:

```
sed: preserving permissions for './sedSjMfzs': Operation not permitted
sed: cannot rename ./sedSjMfzs: Permission denied
```

Can anyone give me some suggestions on why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens when `sed -i` is executed (`strace`):

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "input", O_RDONLY)     = 4
[...]
openat(AT_FDCWD, "./sedMSD2Zj", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 5
[...]
rename("./sedMSD2Zj", "input")          = 0
```

Windows NTFS permissions are much more complex than Linux permissions. I am not familiar with them but it seems that this user is permitted to create files but not to rename them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this script on Windows files from within the subsystem? If so, an easy fix would probably be to move the files into the Ubuntu subsystem and then move them back when you're finished. I think that would be consistent with Hauke's answer since your WSL user probably does not have permission to reach out of the subsystem and change Windows files.